Doble DNS cuando hago el test de DNS (DCdiag /test:dns)
Cuando me asignaron IT Administrator, no era un experto DNS y aun sigo aprendiendo, así que tal vez esto puede ser algo básico, pero me aun acuesta comprender dónde está el error.
Tengo mi AD, DNS etc en un solo dominio con dos domain servers WIN2016, y me di cuenta que tengo un error in la config. de DNS, cuando ejecuto el

cmd DCdiag /test:dns

, al final resulta Broken Delagated domain "local.mydomain.ca.local.mydomain.ca como podrán ver, tengo duplicado el delegate domain, he buscado bastante en la web y solo hacen referencia a un folder en mi subdomain llamado COM, y es ahí donde tendría registrado nuevamente "local.mydomain.ca", si lo había y lo borre pero ejecuto nuevamente el cmd y aun sigue apareciendo el error, lo que encontré es dentro del forrest está así:
forwardLookupZones
        local.mydomain.ca
          _msdsc
             ca
               mydomain
                   local
             dc
             gc
          _sites
          _tcp
          _udp
          ca
            mydomain
                 local

La pregunta aqui es, y espero que no sea muy confusa, dentro del subdomain _msdcs tengo

ca>mydomain>local

y dentro del forrest (local.mydomain.ca) tambien existe

local>mydomain>ca

, que lo mas probable es que aquí esta el error, pero cual debo borrar? el que está dentro de _msdcs o el que esta dentro del main forrest local.mydomain.ca?
Mil gracias de antemano!
